# Nested task inside webApi never fire

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, task-parallel-library

I am playing around TPL in both WebApi app and WPF app.
In WPF app, I got the following code doing what I expected.

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("UI thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Debug.WriteLine("Task 1 thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId))
                    .ContinueWith(ant =>
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Continuation on UI thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                        Task.Factory.StartNew(
                            () => Debug.WriteLine("Task 2 thread is UI thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
                    }, 
                    TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }
```

But in webApi app, the nested task inside continuewith never gets called.
As far as I know, the only different is the SynchronizeContext.
Does anyone know why the nested task never gets called in WebApi?

Comment: I suspect it is called, but the `WriteLine` is being swallowed up elsewhere. Can you try putting in a `int count = 0` and doing a bunch of `Interlocked.Increment(ref count);` and see if you get the correct `count` out?

Comment: I just tried, it still doesn't get called. And I notice something interesting, continueWith is running on the same thread as StartNew, even though I specified to use CurrentSynchronizationContext.